# How to add elements into the array of objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like - 
demo =

```
[{'optionName':'LC_10','parentFilterKey':'automatedTags'},
{'optionName':'LC_11','parentFilterKey':'automatedTags'},
{'optionName':'LC_12','parentFilterKey':'automatedTags'},
{'optionName':'V1','parentFilterKey':'Vendor'},
{'optionName':'V2','parentFilterKey':'Vendor'},
{'optionName':'V3','parentFilterKey':'Vendor'}]
```

and I want to this  -

```
obj = {
'automatedTag': ['LC_11','LC_12','LC_13'],
'vendor':['V1','V2','V3']
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Do you want to convert the first array into the second one? The question is very vague. Please elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `parentFilterKey` and collect `optionName`.

```js
var data = [{ optionName: 'LC_10', parentFilterKey: 'automatedTags' }, { optionName: 'LC_11', parentFilterKey: 'automatedTags' }, { optionName: 'LC_12', parentFilterKey: 'automatedTags' }, { optionName: 'V1', parentFilterKey: 'Vendor' }, { optionName: 'V2', parentFilterKey: 'Vendor' }, { optionName: 'V3', parentFilterKey: 'Vendor' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { optionName, parentFilterKey }) => {
        (r[parentFilterKey] = r[parentFilterKey] || []).push(optionName);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```